# How to fire an event when something in the Database changes in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have an external script that changes some tables in a database.

I want to fire some scripts whenever this happens.

I could do this with a PHP/Perl daemon easily, however I wonder if Laravel has something for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's relevant for what you're trying to do but you can use the Laravel [Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling) to run a command that checks (every minutes or more) if the database changed.

If you can too, fire a command directly from your external script like

```
php path/to/artisan your:command-name
```